`Event doesnt exist` error when integrating anchor wallet on expo app
When attempting to sign a transaction as anchor.Wallet in a react native expo app for a solana program, the error Property Event doesnt exist is given

solana-wallet-adapter is not compatible with react-native so when setting up your anchor wallet connection, you cannot setup the connection with solana-wallet-adapter

Any success here please?
